# Good desktop screen for a web designer / developer

Tags: monitors, web-development, monitor-stand

I'm a web-designer/developer/coder.
Most of my time is spent staring at lines of code, the resultant web pages, and vector graphic layouts. I do occasional bitmap image editing, read technical books as PDFs, and typical office stuff. My web pages can be quite graphically 'busy' with panels that flip and transparency fade effects. Reading low contrast text gives me a headache.

Over many years I've only had to buy three screens, so I'm quite a novice at this. But, given that I spend many hours looking at my screen every day, I need to get it right.

I'm replacing a failed Iiyama E2207WS
(22", 16:10, 1680x1050)

If it hadn't failed I'd still be happy. But as it has I'd like to replace it with something better.

I'm looking for a monitor with the following characteristics:

- 16:10 ratio (width:height)
- 24" diagonal at 1920 x 1200 pixels
- (or 22" diagonal at 1680 x 1050 pixels)
- I'm not a gamer -- although I do enjoy [TriggerRally](http://trigger-rally.sourceforge.net/) :) -- so I don't need great speed, but the old e2207ws did suffer from text *streaking* / *stretching* (?) during scroll
- I don't need it very bright but

  - good contrast is important
  - as is reasonably good colour reproduction
  - (the e2207ws was OK in both respects)
  - plenty of easy colour/colour-temp adjustment might be useful too (see below **)
- I need the screen low and angled to my line of sight

I think I've found a good stand to get the monitor down low and angled, but I'm open to anything better:
[Wearson WS-03A Adjustable LCD Monitor Stand](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wearson-WS-03A-Adjustable-Monitor-100x100mm/dp/B00XUF2GBI/)

I was strongly considering
iiyama ProLite XUB2495WSU-B1
especially given the anti-flicker and low blue light features,
but [this Hexus review](https://hexus.net/tech/reviews/monitors/125210-iiyama-prolite-xub2495wsu-b1/?page=4) suggested that the black levels and contrast are poor.

So I'm now leaning towards the Dell UltraSharp U2415
Good review [here](http://www.tftcentral.co.uk/reviews/dell_u2415.htm), and top choice [here](https://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-24-inch-monitor/)

** ...and leaning away again having read [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/customer-reviews/R3QY56D7YK8ZKJ/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00OA2I362) Amazon review: "*While the overall colour was good, the whites were too blue on mine. Adjusting the Colour Temp in the menu is a waste of time as it auto selects certain temps. 5700k is far too red and 6500 too blue, and nothing in between.*"
And, like the reviewer, I also hate fiddly touch (in)sensitive buttons and ludicrously bright LED 'on' lights.

I'm lost.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: What's your target price range? Also does this need to be available outside the United States?

Comment: A brief search had me also come to pretty much the same monitor: [Dell U2412M for $187.69](https://www.outletpc.com/og4718-dell-u2412m-24--34--1920x1080-60hz-ips-monitor.html?utm_source=og4718-dell-u2412m-24--34--1920x1080-60hz-ips-monitor&utm_medium=shopping%2Bengine&utm_campaign=pcpartpicker&utm_content=Dell%2B-%2BMonitors&sscid=11k3_do5b8)

Comment: Thank you Bennett. Yes, forgot to say I'm in the UK. Checked out your suggestion: latest reviews excellent -- except recessed stand attachment means I (probably) won't be able to use the Wearson, but I'll cross that bridge... Many thanks, just ordered on Amazon UK for £190.

Comment: If you found a product that answers your question you can post this as an answer to help people in the future.

Comment: I shall, Bennett, when I'm successful :) The Dell U2412M that I ordered had a colour cast -- pink/yellow on the left ranging to green/blue on the right. Sent it back and ordered another from a different seller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Answering my own question (it was solved by [Bennett Yeo](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/6047/bennett-yeo) in the comments to my question)*

First I tried the [iiyama ProLite XUB2395WSU-B1](https://iiyama.com/gb_en/products/prolite-xub2395wsu-b1/) as I was happy with iiyama before.
I didn't keep it for long as:

1. the reported max height of 385mm is actually 410mm
2. 1920x1200 is too many pixels to fit into a 22"/22.5" screen
   While it is possible to adjust the font sizes of Operating System display fonts, with such a small pixel size (unless you have the eyes of a hawk) you might well need add-ons/extensions for your browser(s) to increase the font size of every web page.

Then I tried the [Dell U2412M](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-ultrasharp-24-monitor-u2412m/apd/210-agss/monitors-monitor-accessories) as suggested by [Bennett Yeo](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users/6047/bennett-yeo) in the comments to my question.

The first one I purchased had a strong colour cast across the screen: pink/yellow on the left ranging to green/blue on the right. I sent it back and ordered one from another source. And this one I've kept.

White isn't perfectly white, as suggested in some other reviews. But, colours are consistent over the screen and, if I'd had the iiyama, I would probably have activated the 'reduced blue' mode and ended up with exactly the same result.

24" diagonal is right for a 1920x1200 screen: I increased the OS display fonts by 1pt; web pages are comfortable to read without adjustment.

The on/standby light is integral with the on/off button and is a completely unobtrusive gentle orange/blue.

The system for adjusting screen settings is the best I've ever seen. Four blank mechanical buttons on the right (above the on/off). Pressing any button activates the menu. Each option in the menu is adjacent to the button which activates it. Brilliant.

I have the screen on 'text mode', with brightness adjusted down (20) and contrast adjusted up (80). And for me that gives a very comfortable display.

The extra screen 'real-estate' -- 1920x1200 in 24" vs 1650x1080 in 22" -- is a pleasure, as I get more vertical text space for viewing/editing code, and more space overall for editing graphics.

At its lowest, the top edge of the screen is 410mm above the desk, and the bezel adds another 20mm.
I would prefer it lower and, if I purchase another stand to achieve this, I shall post an update to this answer.
NB, if you're thinking of doing the same, the stand attachment area is recessed into the back of the monitor by about 6mm. Which does make attaching/detaching the original stand very easy, but does mean that the Wearson WS-03A Adjustable LCD Monitor Stand that I was thinking of using won't work on its own as it has a 'lip' at the bottom of the attachment plate. It is possible to purchase spacer kits, or simply another stand which fits inside the recess. And remember to check the size of monitor it will hold, quite a few are only only recommended for up to 22".

So I'm currently looking at
[Wearson WS-03A Adjustable LCD Monitor Stand](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wearson-WS-03A-Adjustable-Monitor-100x100mm/dp/B00XUF2GBI/)
plus
[Part King® Vesa Bolt / Screw / Washer / Spacer Kit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B0779C4G8J/ref=asc_df_B0779C4G8J58142109/)
or
[Wearson WS-03UP VESA Monitor Stand](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Wearson-WS-03UP-Adjustable-Detachable-100x100mm/dp/B077WPY471/) on its own.
or...